# Delete old profile picture after uploading new one

Tags: php, laravel

I can upload profile image like this

```
$file_name=$user->id.time().'.'.$request->image->extension();
$request->image->move(public_path('images/profile'),$file_name);
$path="/images/profile/$file_name";
$user->image=$path;
$user->update();
```

I have two questions:
The first one is **How to delete the old image after uploading a new one ?**

The second one is **Is this path the best practice for uploading profile images of users ?**

Answer (score 0):

When using the `public` or `local` driver you can delete the old profile photo like this.

```php
Storage::delete($user->image);
```

in your case you are using a directory inside the public folder (which is not recommended) and you could delete it as follows

```php
File::delete($filename);
```

You will have to do this before saving the new image, so that the previous path is not lost, or save it in a variable if you want to do it later.

Regarding where to save your image it is best to save it in the storage folder.
The `public` disk included in your application's `filesystems` configuration file is intended for files that are going to be publicly accessible. By default, the public disk uses the `local` driver and stores its files in `storage/app/public`.
So you could save the file like this

```php
$path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');
$path; // avatars/ik2uQS5purtLjV42uXjCHnquGTWmnesAaC9JJdit.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you used Media Library Link: https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v10/introduction

```
    public function storeAvatar(AvatarRequest $request): JsonResponse
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
            $file = $request->file('avatar');

            // If has Avatar, delete old avatar
            if ($this->user->getFirstMedia('avatar'))
            {
                $this->user->clearMediaCollection('avatar');
            }

            // Add Avatar Collection name: avatar
            $this->user->addMedia($file)
                ->toMediaCollection('avatar');
        }
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'avatar' => $this->user->getFirstMediaUrl('avatar')
        ]);
    }
```